# Adding process to cgroup returns error "write error: Invalid argument"

Tags: security, cgroup

On Red Hat 8.7 on x86_64 I would like to restrict process to be allowed to use only 50% of CPU time.

I tried to limit a process with cgroups following Red Hat tutorial
[Setting CPU limits to applications using cgroups-v1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/system_design_guide/setting-limits-for-applications_system-design-guide#setting-cpu-limits-to-applications-using-cgroups-v1_setting-limits-for-applications) and I have successfully created cgroup and limit CPU time on specific process on my test computer.

Now I would like to do the same on production computer but I run into a problem. I did:

1. Create new cgroup

   mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/Example/
2. Created 50% CPU time limitation

   echo "1000000" > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/Example/cpu.cfs_period_us

   echo "500000" > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/Example/cpu.cfs_quota_us
3. Add process to cgroup

   echo "2335776" > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/Example/cgroup.procs

Command returns error:

> bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

What does this error means and how to add process to cgroup?

Comment: According to documentation I have tried: `echo 2335776 | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/MyGroup1/tasks` and command executes successfully. But for some reason CPU usage is not restricted for those processes. Any idea why?